# Magento MatrixRate - How to add surcharge fees based on weight?

Tags: magento, webshop

I'm using WebShopApps - MatrixRates to calculate my shipping fees and it works great. I just need to add a surcharge price based on weight on shipping that weight more than 50kg. 
To do this I need to edit the MatrixRate's model but I'm not so comfortable with magento.
Does anyone have any advice/suggestion?

tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you need to edit the module's model? You would just add a line item in the import CSV with a minimum weight of 50000 (assuming you are using grams) and include the surcharge in with the shipping price for that weight increment and any above it.

I've included a screenshot of one of my Matrix Rates tables, if I needed to do what you are suggesting I'd just add a line with a `Weight >=` of 50000.

[image]

Comment: I'm not adding a new row for weight more than 50kg because I need to calculate the surcharge fees like this: (fees for < 50kg) + [(weight - 50kg) * fees]

Comment: Ah, I see (sorry, I didn't pick that up).  Well if it was me I'd just bite the bullet and get the Handling Fees extension by WebShopApps that can work in conjunction with Matrix rates and can handle weight based handling fee calculations. http://www.webshopapps.com/handling-fees-matrix.html